# How to initialize or assign the values to a collection in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

How do you pass a view model to a class that assigned the properties using the constructor? See my comment in codes.

```
public class Foo 
{
    public Foo() 
    { 
        Bars = new HashSet<Bar>();
    }

    public Foo(FooVm foo) 
    {
        FooId = foo.FooId;
        FooName = foo.FooName;
        // Initialize Bars by passing foo. How? Or is it possible?
    }

    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar 
{
    public Bar() { }

    public Bar(BarVm bar) 
    {
        BarId = bar.BarId;
        BarName = bar.BarName;
    }

    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public string BarName { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var fooBar = new Foo(fooVm);
```

I want something above. That initialize the `Foo` class and at the same time initializes the `Bars` collection like so:

```
var fooBar = new Foo(fooVm);
fooBar.Bars = fooVm.Bars
                   .Select(b => new Bar { 
                      BarId = b.BarId,
                      BarName = b.BarName });
```

Comment: Why can't you just put the "what I am doing right now" code into the `Foo(FooVm foo)` constructor (and initialise Bars there too).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yea. I've been thinking about that but is it okay doing that way?

Comment: It's ok doing it like that, unless you want to hide the logic of selecting the Bars - but since you are just making a copy, that seems unlikely. If you did want to hide it, you could pass an `IEnumerable<Bar>` instead (and implement it outside the `Foo` class).

Comment: @MatthewWatson Hi. Think you can site some examples on how to do it? It would be great reference for others.